# Pandas - Create groups with unique values in it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, grouping

I would like to ask if it is possible to divide pandas DataFrame  into groups where values from two columns are unique within the group? Name column is primary key.

input:

```
| name   | num_1 | num_2  |
|--------|-------|--------|
| name_1 |   5   |   12   |
| name_2 |   5   |   12   |
| name_3 |   5   |   12   |
| name_4 |   7   |   14   |
| name_5 |   7   |   14   |
| name_6 |   8   |   14   |
| name_7 |   8   |   14   |
| name_8 |   9   |   13   |
| name_9 |   9   |   13   |
| name_10|   9   |   13   |
```

output:

```
| name   | num_1 | num_2  | group_id |
|--------|-------|--------|----------|
| name_1 |   5   |   12   |    1     |
| name_2 |   5   |   12   |    2     |
| name_3 |   5   |   12   |    3     |
| name_4 |   7   |   14   |    1     |
| name_5 |   7   |   14   |    2     |
| name_6 |   8   |   14   |    3     |
| name_7 |   8   |   14   |    4     |
| name_8 |   9   |   13   |    1     |
| name_9 |   9   |   13   |    2     |
| name_10|   9   |   13   |    3     |
```

Basically the num_1 and num_2 cannot repeat in the group. Is there any way how to do it with pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`Groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
In [1450]: df['group_id'] = df.groupby('num_2').cumcount() + 1

In [1451]: df
Out[1451]: 
      name  num_1  num_2  group_id
0   name_1      5     12         1
1   name_2      5     12         2
2   name_3      5     12         3
3   name_4      7     14         1
4   name_5      7     14         2
5   name_6      8     14         3
6   name_7      8     14         4
7   name_8      9     13         1
8   name_9      9     13         2
9  name_10      9     13         3
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I ran it 7k of record and it did not divided the groups correctly. In the group_id 1 there were a lot of duplicates in num_2 column and a few in the num_1 column.

Comment: Also in your output the group_id: 1 contains value 14 two times

Comment: @pipikej As far as I understood the question, you want a unique combination of `num_1` and `num_2`. So in my solution, group_id `1` contains `7 14` and `8 14`, which are unique combinations.

Comment: I did not want unique combinations of the numbers. I wanted in the group all possible combinations of `num_1` and `num_2` where neither of them is duplicated within the group id. So combination of `7 14` and `8 14` in the same group is not possible. As you can see in my output the value 14 is there 4 times, that means there must be at least 4 groups, because the same group cannot contain value 14 more then once. The same rule applies to num_1.

Comment: Got it. Please check my updated answer. @pipikej

Comment: That seems working. Thank you a lot sir.